# Excel vba reference image in header

Tags: vba, excel

How do I reference an image in the right header of an Excel document (2007 or greater) in order to assign it to a Shape variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer myself after much head scratching. Header images are not Shape objects they are Graphic objects

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193679.aspx

Use the PageSetup object members to reference the Graphic e.g.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196670.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Final code:

```
Sub GetHeaderImage()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ps As PageSetup
Dim headpic As Graphic

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set ps = ws.PageSetup
Set headpic = ps.RightHeaderPicture

End Sub
```